# Align image with text in CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to align this image with text in the box. Css for box and image:

```
#msg_b {
    word-wrap: break-word;
    background:#fefefe;
    padding:5px;
    min-height:15px;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    position:relative;
    margin-left:30px;
    border-radius:5px;
    border: 1px solid #d5d5d5;
}
.avatar {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

and the result, the image cannot align with box. Please help!

Comment: Please, post your html.

Comment: I do not have the right to post image , so please test it for me! coz my reputation is under 10

Comment: I think you misspelled `avatar`... :)

Comment: How can we possibly test it without seeing your HTML? Also, post a link to your image and somebody will embed it for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should try to create a div and put your text and your image in the same div with the style you provided.

something like:

```
    <div id="msg_b">Your text goes here
    <img src="YOUR_IMAGE_URL" class="avartar" />
    </div>
```

the position of the image could be changed from right to left adding

```
    float:left;
```

to the style class for your image.
This worked for me. Hope it helps.

Comment: wow! It works! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have to keep their position to inline-block or inline and then set the vertical alignment!

```css
img {
  max-width: 200px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  
  padding: 1em 2em;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2014/04/20/12/30/thumb-328420_640.jpg" /><span>Good Job</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out ( add `display:block` to both elements ):

```
#msg_b{
    display: block;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    background:#fefefe;
    padding:5px;
    min-height:15px;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    position:relative;
    margin-left:30px;
    border-radius:5px;
    border: 1px solid #d5d5d5;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
.avatar {
    display: block;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    vertical-align:middle;

}
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/luispa/kd4kjdck/47/)**

Comment: The problem is if the second avatar display then it is on the same line, I want to put the n avatar to new line. Please help!

Comment: I update my answer base on your criteria